# Cannot register new user " NoMethodError in My_devise/registrations#new "

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am able to run rake db:migrate without any problem and the database is generated successfully. When I try browse sign_up page to create a new user I get the **Action Conctroller: Exception Caught**

> NoMethodError in My_devise/registrations#new

Showing app/views/my_devise/registrations/new.html.haml where line #2 raised:

```
undefined method `logo' for nil:NilClass
```

Extracted source (around line #2):

```
1: = semantic_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :id => 'checkout') do |f|
2:   -if current_label.logo.url.present?
3:     =image_tag current_label.logo.url
4:     %br
5:   .row
```

Comment: Your `current_label` is `nil`. How is it set?

Comment: Could always add a `- unless current_label.nil?`

Comment: Thank you `-unless current_lable.nil?` worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using HAML I'll show the example in HAML as well.

Most likely you'll want to add a `nil?` check for the object that you're referencing (since if it isn't created through Devise yet you won't be able to access it of course!)

```
- unless current_label.nil?
 =image_tag current_label.logo.url
 %br
```